# Y a-t-il toujours élision du e de « je » quand le mot suivant commence par une voyelle ?

Tags: grammaire

Pour « j'étudie », c'est correct.

Mais je pense que pour « quand dois-je utiliser », ce n'est pas vrai. C'est vrai ? Quelle est la règle ?

Answer (score 5):

La règle dit que l'élision est faite lorsque le mot qui suit commence par une voyelle ou un h aspiré. Ce n'est pas le cas lorsqu'il y a une inversion « sujet-verbe ».

> ([réf.](https://docplayer.fr/22618331-L-inversion-pronominale-histoire-et-analyse.html)) 2.2 Élision 
>   L’élision du « schwa » est régulière. Elle concerne, pour les variétés pertinentes, les formes « -je »,  et « -ce ». À la différence des mêmes formes employées en position préverbale, l’élision n’est pas obligatoire (même si elle extrêmement fréquente) et elle n’est pas notée orthographiquement : 
>   •
>   « Puis-je avoir » ([Z(ə)av-]) vs. «<s>Je avais</s> »

- Devrais-je y aller ?  — Ai-je étudié pour rien ?

Voici ce que dit LBU à ce sujet (il n'y a pas de raison bien particulière pour cette orthographe).

> L'élision n'est pas toujours marquée dans « ce », « je », « quelque », « presque », « quoique », « lorsque «  et  « puisque ».
>   Les pronoms sujets « je » et « ce » s'écrivent « j' » et « c' » quand ils précèdent le verbe, mais en entier quand ils le suivent :
>
> - J'aime. C'est vrai. — Suis-JE arrivé ? [suiJArivé] — Est-CE achevé ? [èSAchevé].